# How to install libsane-perl >=0.05 in Lubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installation, dependencies

After reinstalling my Lubuntu 12.04 system I want to get back some programs, amongst which **[gscan2pdf](https://askubuntu.com/a/166181/47206)**

When I try to install the deb file in gdebi I get this

[image]

in synaptic I have tried to install that dependency but it is an older version

[image]

How to install the newest version?

Comment: @tijybba - if he were using quantal 0.05 would already be available stock http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libsane-perl&searchon=names&suite=quantal&section=all

Comment: @aking1012- Thanks for pointing it , sorry [cipricus](http://askubuntu.com/users/47206/cipricus) for posting irrelevant comment , i will delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That dependency is only available for [Quantal](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsane-perl) at the moment unless you install it from some other ppa.

[Here's an x64 build for precise](https://launchpad.net/~alex-p/+archive/notesalexp-precise/+build/3598121). And an x86 build for precise [here](https://launchpad.net/~alex-p/+archive/notesalexp-precise/+build/3598122)

[Launchpad has a search function](http://launchpad.net/+search?field.text=libsane-perl+0.05+precise)

See also: [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) and add `ppa:alex-p/notesalexp-precise` to Software Sources.

Comment: after editing your answer i'll delete my previous comments here